# Do the NYSE and the NASDAQ Stock Exchanges Have the Same Hours?

Tags: stock-exchanges, nasdaq, nyse

I am wondering if the NYSE and the NASDAQ stock exchanges have identical trading hours? In other words, will a stock listed on the NYSE trade during the same hours as a stock listed on the NASDAQ? Thanks!

Comment: From https://www.kiplinger.com/investing/602886/stock-market-trading-hours#:~:text=Regular%20trading%20hours%20for%20the,p.m.%2C%20except%20stock%20market%20holidays. - "Regular trading hours for the U.S. stock market, including the New York Stock Exchange (NYSE) and the Nasdaq Stock Market (Nasdaq), are 9:30 a.m. to 4 p.m." (times are Eastern).